# postgresql docker throwing: initdb: error: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": No error information

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a postgresql docker service declared in a compose file like below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres_data:
    image: postgres:14-alpine3.16
    container_name: postgres_data
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5433:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passwprd
      POSTGRES_DB: public
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

The databse volume is hosted on the cwd `./data/postgres`. This worked for a long time but when I re started the container: `docker-compose down && docker-compose up`, I started getting this error:

```
initdb: error: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": No error information
```

why is this happening? checking the directory permission I see:

```
drwx------ 19  70 myuser 27 Mar  7 09:17 postgres
```

Is there something wrong here? I have not changed the image version.